# Images aren't loading in .jar file

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, embedded-resource

I am aware the question has been asked before. However, I have tried all the solutions and none seem to work. I have created a simple GUI program using `javax.swing`, and of course it works perfectly in IntelliJ. However, its consequent jar file has quite a few issues. First and foremost, none of the images even display. I have been importing them as so:

```
img = new ImageIcon((ImageIO.read(new File("image_name.png"))));
```

I found a solution suggesting I use:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("res/name.png"));
```

However, not only does it not load in the jar, it takes 5 seconds for the program to even launch in the compiler.

This is getting extremely frustrating, making this an executable. 
If it's of any use, the `JButton` components on the jar also don't seem to work. Whenever you click them, they remain pressed but nothing happens further. 
I understand this isn't loads of info, but I would nontheless appreciate any help you can give. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming that the images are included within the jar then `img = new ImageIcon((ImageIO.read(new File("image_name.png"))))` should be `mg = new ImageIcon((ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("image_name.png"))))`. The path is relative to the class trying to load the source, you could use `img = new ImageIcon((ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/image_name.png"))))` to load the image from the `res` directory located from the top of the class path offset

Comment: Try to print absolute path of `new File(".")` and you will see where your images are being looked for when you use `new File("image_name.png")`. What you seems to want is reading *resources* which are placed in same jar. If that is the case read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/load-icon-image-exception

Comment: Verify if the images are located on the disk or stored in the jar file